Full page width image in PDF made in quarto
I'm trying to get an image to span the full width of the first page of a PDF document I'm making in quarto, but everything I've tried leaves at least a small gap on one or both sides of the image. The original image size is 8.38cm by 20.97cm, I don't mind if I lose part of the image, I just don't want any gaps.
I don't have much experience with latex so I'm at a loss. This is the best result I've got, but still leaves a sliver of white either side:
\begin{figure}[H]
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=23cm]{../images/titlestrip.png}}
\end{figure}

Here's what else I've tried (amongst other things):
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
 \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-2.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=23cm]{../images//titlestrip.png}}}}
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.25in}{-1.25in}
\begin{textblock*}{24cm}[0.5,0.5](10.5cm,17cm)
    \includegraphics[width=22cm]{../images/titlestrip.png}
\end{textblock*}
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{../images/titlestrip.png}
\end{figure}
\end{flushright}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
  \begin{minipage}{2\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=21cm]{../images/titlestrip.png}
  \end{figure}
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
    \includegraphics[height=8.47cm]{../images/titlestrip.png}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=23cm]{../images/titlestrip.png}}%
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:key}
\end{figure}

\newlength{\offsetpage}
\setlength{\offsetpage}{1.0cm}
\newenvironment{widepage}{\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}%
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{2in}}%
{\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{widepage}
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=23cm]{../images/titlestrip.png}}%
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:key}
  \end{widepage}
\end{figure}

In this image, the red block is the image position I currently have, the green either side is the extra space I'd like it to cover. The green square is another image in the correct position.


If you want the image at a specific position and if you don't use a caption, get rid of the figure environment around it.

Maybe try using the background package? Here is what worked for me:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\title{Bunch of text}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1.0,
  angle=0,
  opacity=0.95,
  contents={
    \includegraphics{red.png}}}

\BgThispage

\end{document}

and this is the output:

EDIT: after I submitted this response I found the https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/clrstrip/clrstrip.pdf package, which might be an easier solution. Thought I would add this to my response here in case it's useful for someone in the future.

With some adjustments to the scale and position this worked perfectly - thank you!

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Adjustbox on the top}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\paperwidth, height=100, frame=0pt, opacity=0.8}
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=10]{red.png}
end{adjustbox}

\newgeometry{a4paper, margin=2cm}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}


According to these solutions from tex.stackexchange.com, you should use \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{...}}

Yeah I went through those too, unfortunately it still leaves blank space at the sides for me

I've add new answer with adjustbox
